# How to write a function that takes a string and a generic type as parameters?

Tags: ios, json, swift, generics

I'm using a library called Gloss to help parse JSON data.  As a result I've created structs that are of type Glossy:

```
struct LoyaltyCard: Glossy {
let id: Int

init?(json: JSON) {
    guard let __id: Int = "id" <~~ json
      else { return nil }
}
```

I have many different Glossy structs and want to pass them into a function along with a string but I keep getting an error: " Cannot invoke 'getMemberInfo' with an argument list of type '(String, memberData: LoyaltyCard.Type)'", here is an abbreviated version of my function:

```
 func getMemberInfo<T: Glossy> (memberDataRequest: String, memberData:T) {
 let urlAccess = "\(baseURL)/api/\(memberDataRequest)"

///////code////////////

let data = object as! NSData

              let jsonInfo: AnyObject? = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))

              let jsonArray = jsonInfo as! NSArray
                  if let dict = jsonArray[0] as? JSON //This means as type Gloss
                      {
                    let loyaltyID= LoyaltyCard(json: dict)
                    print(loyaltyID?.id)

                  }
                }
```

Any ideas how to make this function work?

Comment: for example:  getMemberInfo(memberDataRequest: "Member", memberData: LoyaltyCard)

Comment: When you say `memberData: LoyaltyCard`, you are passing a type, `LoyaltyCard`, as the parameter. But you want to pass an instance of something that conforms to `Glossy` (e.g. an instance of `LoyaltyType`, not just the type itself). The error is telling you that it doesn't know what to do with this type you passed to it rather than some instance of something that conforms to `Glossy`.

Comment: That makes sense,  I have a bunch of structs that are of type Glossy, if I want to pass in one of those structs, what do you reccomend I set the function parameter type to be?

Comment: Once I receive the JSON data I want to populate the struct I passed in with that JSON data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113694/discussion-between-rob-and-swiftyjd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm inferring from your code sample and from your comments, that you don't necessarily want to pass a `Glossy` type *to* `getMemberInfo`, but rather that the key requirement is that you want to perform a network request and return a `Glossy` type.

While I get what you were trying to do, I would personally retire the generic approach, and just use a [protocol extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521). You end up with a method that can be called for any `Glossy` type. And if this protocol extension method returns a type `Self`, that will end up returning whatever `Glossy` type from which you happen to call it.

First, let's step back and be clear as to what the `Glossy` protocol might look like. At the very least, you'd have some failable initializer (plus whatever else your types needed):

```
protocol Glossy {
    init?(json: [String: AnyObject])
}
```

(Note, I'm not using `JSON` type, but feel free if you want. I personally just use Swift collections for parsed JSON, but do whatever you want.)

I'd then define a `static` method in a protocol extension to perform the request. The following method uses `NSURLSession`, but if you use Alamofire or something else, the basic idea is the same:

```
extension Glossy {
    static func performMemberRequest(memberDataRequest: String, completionHandler:(Self?, ErrorType?) -> ()) -> NSURLSessionTask {
        let urlAccess = "\(baseURL)/api/\(memberDataRequest)"

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlAccess)!)
        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data where error == nil else {
                completionHandler(nil, error)
                return
            }

            do {
                if let array = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? [[String: AnyObject]],
                    let dictionary = array.first {
                    completionHandler(Self(json: dictionary), nil)
                } else {
                    completionHandler(nil, GlossyError.InvalidJSONError)
                }
            } catch let parseError {
                completionHandler(nil, parseError)
            }
        }

        task.resume()

        return task
    }
}
```

Note, there are a few notable issues entailed in the above:

- Network requests should always be performed asynchronously. So use asynchronous pattern like `completionHandler` rather than trying to return some object immediately.

  If you're going to return anything, the only thing you should be returning is the `NSURLSessionTask` object so the caller has the option to capture that and cancel requests, should you want that functionality.
- I changed the name of the method to be more descriptive and conform to Cocoa naming conventions.
- As an aside, your code suggests that your API returned an array and you're just grabbing the first dictionary. That seems like a curious pattern, but I've followed that, above. If you really were returning an array, it strikes me that you did that because you contemplate a scenario where you could be returning multiple items. In that case, I would advise iterate through the whole array and have the completion handler return `[Self]?` (an array of `Glossy` objects) rather than just `Self?` (i.e. only the first one).

  Furthermore, I wouldn't personally advise a structure that returns an array as the top level item. How does that web service report errors? I'd have a dictionary structure that returned success/failure and/or return code and the like. And then have a dedicated key for results which would be your array of results.

  But I didn't tackle any of these broader API issues above, but rather followed the pattern in your code snippet. But these are considerations you might want to think about.
- In my example, I didn't dispatch these `completionHandler` calls back to the main queue, but that's often a very useful pattern (avoids synchronization problems, UI updates, etc.). It's trivial to do, but I wanted to keep the above relatively simple.

But, let's step aside from the details of your API and the like. Let's focus on the notion that you want a `static` method defined in the protocol extension, (and it can therefore be called from any type that conforms to `Glossy`). For example, I can then define the `LoyaltyCard` class with the required initializer:

```
struct LoyaltyCard: Glossy {
    let id: Int

    init?(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        guard let id = json["id"] as? Int else {
            return nil
        }

        self.id = id
    }
}
```

Having done all that, I can now invoke the `static` method of `Glossy` protocol extension on `LoyaltyCard`, for example:

```
LoyaltyCard.performMemberRequest(memberDataRequest) { loyaltyCard, error in
    guard let loyaltyCard = loyaltyCard where error == nil else {
        print(error)
        return
    }

    // do something with loyaltyCard here
    print(loyaltyCard)
}

// but don't use it here
```

---

There's a lot there, but I don't want you to get lost in the details. But I do hope you grok the key concepts here: Don't pass a `Glossy` type *to* your method, nor use a generic: Instead use protocol extension. And avoid synchronous network requests, so instead use a asynchronous pattern like the `completionHandler` pattern.